# Reduce a 3 channel OpenCV Mat to a single-channel one using a LUT

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I want to reduce the depth of an RGB image (24bit) to one byte by reducing the color space and using a color map where each 3-byte triple R/G/B is mapped to a one-byte color map value.

I am therefore looking for a performant way to create a a single-channel Mat (*CV8UC1*) out of a 3-channel Mat (*CV8UC3*) using a lookup table. This step is time-critical, as it is done for each frame of a video stream.

The [LUT](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#lut) function would be great, but as far as I understand, the resulting Mat will contain was much channels as the input mat had.

Do you have any idea how this could be accomplished?

Comment: Yeah, that would require a LUT for each channel and then you'd have to `OR` the results together or something. If you have the freedom to order the color map however you want, it would be easier to find a mapping operation and do it mathematically. Of course the easiest is to simply truncate the bits of each channel keeping only the high 2 (or 1) bits and concatenate, but that would leave you with only 64 (or 8) indices into your color map.